# In the proof of Caratheodory's lemma, why do we stop at $d+1$ points?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

I have to proof caratheodorys lemma for my oral exam. The proof is given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_%28convex_hull%29).
I dont get the last part.
 "This process can be repeated until x is represented as a convex combination of at most d + 1 points in P"
Why do we have to stop at d+1 points ?
An explanation of that would be really appriciated:)

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/417285/173147

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the proof states, for $k > d+1$, the $k-1$ points $x_2 − x_1, \ldots, x_k − x_1$ must be linearly dependent, since they are in a $d$ dimensional space.

For $k \le d+1$, it is possible that the $k-1$ points $x_2 − x_1, \ldots, x_k − x_1$ are linearly independent, so it is not necessarily true that the process of eliminating points can continue.

Comment: ty for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck on your exam!