# Why if $k>d+1$ then $\{x_j-x_1\}_{j=2}^k\subset \mathbb R^d$ is linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, convex-analysis, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

I don't get this step in proof of [Carathéodory's theorem (convex hull)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(convex_hull))
Why:

> Suppose k > d + 1 (otherwise, there is nothing to prove). Then, the points $x_2 − x_1, ..., x_k − x_1$ are linearly dependent

Why is this true?

How can we cay these points are linearly dependent?

Comment: There are at least $d+1$ such points. The dimension of the space is $d$, so the maximum linearly independent set can have only $d$ elements. Hence, one of them is linearly dependent on the others.

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/417285/173147

Answer (score 1):

Note that $k > d+1$, and that our points are vectors in $\Bbb R^d$.  In $\Bbb R^d$ (or any $d$-dimensional vector space), any set consisting of more than $d$ vectors is linearly dependent.

Comment: How would I prove this? Using gaussian elimination?

Comment: What is there to prove?  This is the definition of dimension.  If you want to prove that $\Bbb R^d$ is indeed a $d$-dimensional space, it suffices to consider the usual basis.  If you want the proof that every basis for a vector space contains the same number of elements (which is to say that dimension is well-defined), then you're looking for the [dimension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces).

Answer (score 0):

What is the cardinality of $\{x_2 − x_1, ..., x_k − x_1\}$? Now remember that there aren't any linearly independent set of cardinality greater than $d$ in $\Bbb R^d$.